# How to create a sub-library in the "uses" clause?

Tags: delphi

Back there when I use Delphi 2006 it was:

```
 uses System, SysUtils, StrUtils, Windows, Dialogs, WinApi;
```

But recently we can use:

```
 uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics;
```

**How this change works?** Does they separated the `System.pas` into `System.*.pas` or did they created a new clause for separating function by types in a single library?

**How do I modify my old libraries to work like this?** I want to do make something like: MyLib.Logic, MyLib.Arrays, MyLib.NetWork etc.

Comment: You just need to read the docs for xe2

Comment: Just rename your unit filenames to: `MyLib.Logic.pas`, `MyLib.Arrays.pas`, `MyLib.NetWork.pas` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are encountering are known as [**Unit Scope Names**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Unit_Scope_Names).  The various RTL and VCL unit names were changed to better differentiate which units are Platform-specific and which are Cross-Platform.  Not only are the unit names using namespaces, which have been around since Delphi.NET was introduced, but now even the unit filenames themselves are now namespaced as well, which is new.

If you are not writing cross-platform code, then you are encouraged to use the new syntax:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics
```

However, if you want to write cross-platform code, or just have legacy code that you need to maintain, then continue using the original syntax:

```
uses
  System, SysUtils, StrUtils, ...;
```

And then make sure that the "Winapi", "System", "Vcl", "Fmx", etc prefixes are included in the "Unit Scope Names" field of the Project Options as needed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the cross-platform restriction? I could not find any reference to it in the help.

Comment: Yes, cross platform part of this answer is wide of the mark. Hard to see uses Windows as xplat.

Comment: Obviously, the Windows unit is not xplat, but many other units are. Take the Controls unit. That is a good example of unit scope names in action. There are separate `Fmx.Controls` and `Vcl.Controls` units. You can either IFDEF your code to `uses Fmx.Controls` or `uses Vcl.Controls` based on the project type, or you can just `uses Controls` like before and then specify either Fmx or Vcl in the Unit Scope Names field in the Project Options.

Comment: @remy but you can't do anything useful xplat like that. Try it and see. The two controls units are not even remotely interchangeable. You don't get the xplat design I think. You don't have VCL on Windows, and FMX on Mac, say. For xplat you have FMX everywhere.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: We're not talking about the rest of the unit's code, so it doesn't matter if that code is xplat or not. We're only talking about the `uses` clause here. Embarcadero introduced unit scope names so they could share commonly-named units in VCL and FMX projects while being able to keep them separated.

Comment: Agreed. I'd just say this is about supporting multiple frameworks and nothing to do with xplat.  it just happens that one of the frameworks is xplat.

Answer (score 4):

Just open your old files in the ide, and in the project manager rename the unit. It'll automatically change the unit name inside the file.

After that, open and recompile your old projects to make sure that you refer to the right unit names.

The only advantage of these dots over something like an underscore seems to be that you can get a list of matching "sublibraries" in code completion.

The part before any dots shouldn't be called a "namespace", because it doesn't work like one.

Comment: Yes it is almost funny that namespaces contain units. It needs to be the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

They're called `namespaces`, and they've been around since around Delphi 7, or so, while they were preparing to release Delphi 8 (Delphi for .NET). They were added  to support the .NET side of things. They're documented in [Using Namespaces with Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi).

Comment: Actually, the names in question are **Unit Scope Names**, which are a little bit different than **Namespaces**.

Comment: Are you sure about "since Delphi 6 or 7" part?

Comment: @user539484 dots were not considered special chars (thus you could not write `uses BBB` if your unit was named `unit AAA.BBB;`) but the very dot was told to be normally supported.

Comment: @Arioch 'The, what you just described is merely a relaxation of syntax for unit *identifiers*.

Comment: well, yes. It just was maid so that same sources could be used in Delphi.Net and Delphi.Win32

Comment: @Arioch 'The, i believe what Delphi.NET didnt exist at the D6 times yet, so that statement looks quite random for me.

Comment: @user539484: They were preparing for .NET at the time, though, as well as winding down with Kylix. You can see remnants of both in the source code (even today) of thr RTL. As it seems to be important enough for you to be worrying about, though, would you like me to change it to something more generic in time frame?

Comment: @Ken White, Delphi 6 - May 2001, **.NET 1.0 - Feb 2002**, Kylix 3 - past Jul 2002, Delphi 7 - Aug 2002, **Delphi 8 for .NET - Dec 2003**.

Comment: @user539484: Why are you obsessing over such a minor detail? It doesn't matter. Wait... Let me edit it one more time for you, since you seem to be **really, really worried about it**. If that's not enough to make you happy, I'm sorry. It doesn't matter enough to waste any more time on. Anyone wanting to know **exactly* when it was added can find it easily enough; there's a feature timeline here on SO somewhere. (I don't need it, so I'm not going to search for it.) :-)

Comment: @Ken White, that's because I wasn't sure you are correct with your answer.

Comment: @user539484 - but if to recall who was .Net lead architect, perhaps he leaked some info at least about large details, like that .Net would use system like Java packages. Though that is really but a minor detail today.